# How to unset certain values submitted from dynamic form?

Tags: php, post, filtering, unset

I have a dynamic form <s>that uses variable variables</s> and it works well, but I came to an issue where some POST values must be removed once they are processed by the form's submission.

Due to the nature of <s>variable variables and</s> this dynamic form's programming that builds INSERT and UPDATE queries dynamically, I need to remove these values from the `$_POST` once they've been processed into a single variable.

The partial form processing section is in a foreach loop and contains:

```
$Fields = array();
$Values = array();
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value ) :
    if (Contains("month", $key)) unset($_POST);
    if (Contains("day", $key)) unset($_POST);
    if (Contains("year", $key)) unset($_POST);
    if (Contains("hour", $key)) unset($_POST);
    if (Contains("minute", $key)) unset($_POST);
    if (Contains("second", $key)) unset($_POST);
    $Fields[] = "`$key`";
    $Values[] = isNull($value, $DBName);
endforeach;

$sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO $TableName (".implode(",",$Fields).") VALUES (".implode(",",$Values).")";
```

The `Contains()` function has:

```
function Contains($searchWord, $fromString) {
    if (is_array($fromString)) :
        reset($fromString);
        $key = key($fromString);
        return strpos($key, $searchWord) !== FALSE;
    else:
        return strpos($fromString, $searchWord) !== FALSE;
    endif;
}
```

I tried everything I can think of including:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value ) :
    if (Contains("month", $key)) unset($_POST[$key]);
    if (Contains("day", $key)) unset($_POST[$key]);
    if (Contains("year", $key)) unset($_POST[$key]);
    if (Contains("hour", $key)) unset($_POST[$key]);
    if (Contains("minute", $key)) unset($_POST[$key]);
    if (Contains("second", $key)) unset($_POST[$key]);
endforeach;
```

as `$key` should contain the name of the POST field that I am trying to `unset()` but they do not unset. Any ideas?

Comment: I can provide you a much more refined/professional method if you provide some more details in your question.  Please provide a realistic `$_POST` array that you might receive and your expected built query (with the variables replaced with their values).  Your query is not secure -- I can fix that for you.

Comment: There are no "variable-variables" in your question; I'm removing that tag.

Answer (score 0):

No sooner did I rewrite and simplify my original question when doing so gave me an idea that seems to have done the trick. Rather than using unset, I used continue:

```
if (Contains("month", $key)) continue;
if (Contains("day", $key)) continue;
if (Contains("year", $key)) continue;
if (Contains("hour", $key)) continue;
if (Contains("minute", $key)) continue;
if (Contains("second", $key)) continue;
```